# error installing wireshark on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireshark, apt-get, ubuntu-16.04

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wireshark : Depends: wireshark-qt but it is not going to be installed or
                  wireshark-gtk but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is the output.
I have tried all possible solutions given on askubuntu and other similar forums. I have also tried all commands such as autoremove, clean, install -f, upgrade, update, etc.

I just don't understand what's the problem here. Also i installed synaptic package manager and tried to install it but upon selecting wireshark, it gives broken package error and its properties says it conflicts on ethereal ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9zCm.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4uKx.jpg

Kindly help.

Comment: Don't mix repositories, and do `apt-get update` before every install. Wireshark-common version number is currently 2.0.2+ga16e22e-1 ( http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/wireshark-common )

Answer (score 0):

Try to install wireshark-qt and wireshark-gtk separately.

```
apt-get install whireshark-qt

apt-get install whireshark-gtk
```

Then run:

```
apt-get install whireshark
```

Comment: Nope already tried that, each of them gives some other dependency error.    

`wireshark-qt : Depends: libwireshark8 (>= 2.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: wireshark-common (= 2.2.1+ga6fbd27-1~xenial1) but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: I think its something related to the error which synaptic gave me. Kindly refer to the images.

Comment: Have you added the PPA?
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireshark-dev/stable

Comment: Yes of course i have done that.

Comment: apt-get install whireshark --fix-missing?

Comment: same error mate. I'm almost certain it won't go away this easily. It requires modifications of some files that i don't know of.

Comment: Hmm, I had same problem with other programs, and they was "solved" by doing what I described. I will follow this